# JQuery Não permitir Click em um Botão que tenha uma determinada Classe CSS

Tags: jquery

Bom dia Pessoal, tenho uma aplicação com JQuery EasyUI, e sempre chamo as ações de click dos botões com o JQuery, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
$("#btnEditar").click(function(){
  ...
});
```

Acontece que quando ao se clicar no botão e o mesmo estiver desabilitado, continua executando a ação de Click do JQuery.

Gostaria de saber se seria possível executar o CLick do Botão apenas se o mesmos estiver sem determinada classe css, no meu caso .l-btn-disabled. Efetuei o teste conforme abaixo porém não funcionou:

```
$("#btnEditar").not(".l-btn-disabled").click(function(){
  ...
});
```

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: esse elemento `#btnEditar` é um `button` ou um `input[type=button]`?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar assim, fazendo uso do [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("#btnEditar:not('.l-btn-disabled')").click(function(){
```

Porem repara que estás usar um ID no teu seletor, e ID têm de ser únicos. Usa classes nos buttons que queres selecionar em vêz de ID.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/my78aLr1/